# unable to launch identity homepage through tomcat. not able to connect to mysql although able to connect through mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, tomcat, sailpoint

I am a beginner to sailpoint and currently using identityiq and I am unable to connect to identityiq homepage. Probable reason is that my tomcat is unable to connect to Mysql server.

MYSQL hosted on default port 3306.
Tomcat on default port 8080

However, when I try to connect DB using Workbench I was able to and could create the table using the CREATE Table scripts on IDENTITYIQ database schema.

I see the MYSQL server running in services.

[image]

I run the IIQ CONSOLE in the webapps and get this error:

> D:\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-9.0.20\webapps\identityiq\WEB-INF\bin>iiq console
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'versionChecker' defined in class path resource [configBeans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to check IdentityIQ database version: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)

[image]

In the browser I get this connection failure error

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /identityiq
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.20

[image]

Comment: I have also observe this issue if mysqld.exe was not closed gracefully on windows and system gets restarted.

Answer (score 1):

What is your version of MySQL? and IIQ version. If your MySQL db version is 8.0.11 then the out of the box MySQL driver that is shipped with IIQ may not be compatible with MySQL db. Check [this blog which refers to similar issue](https://www.idmworks.com/sailpoint-7-2-p2-with-mysql-8-compatibility-issue/). You may need to manually create IIQ and Identity Plugin users and grant privileges - commands are also available in the above blog.